# resolved : JqGrid client side searching when user types in in single search box ( below is working grid)

Tags: search, jqgrid, filtering

I have used solution and code from other member's answer . thanks for their help . here is working grid : http://jsfiddle.net/x6t24u8s/1/

I am very new to jqgrid and I am looking filtering to work on client side in a single search box as user types in  .  I'll get data one time from server and then filter in local .

```
Here is my jsfiddle ( I have took example from other questions)
     but it doesn't seem to be working .
```

Can someone please point to me in right direction .

Top 2 lines define text box and table for list . below is code for jqgrid .

```
            http://jsfiddle.net/2b1yta0j/5/

        <input type="text" name="a" id="searchText" value="test2"/>
        <table id="list"></table>

              var mydata = [
                        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"aest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"best2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"cest3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
                        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"dest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"eest2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"fest3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
                        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"gest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"hest2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"iest3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
                        {id:"10",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"jest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"xest2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"12",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"yest3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
                        {id:"13",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"zest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"aest2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"15",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"best3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
                        {id:"16",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"cest",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
                        {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"dest2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
                        {id:"18",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"eest3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
                    ];
                    var grid = $("#list");
                    grid.jqGrid({
                        data: mydata,
                        datatype: "local",
                        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
                        colModel:[
                            {name:'id',index:'id', key: true, width:70, sorttype:"int"},
                            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
                            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
                            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
                            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
                        ],
                        pager:'#pager',
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                        sortname: 'id',
                        sortorder: 'asc',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        height: "100%",
                        caption: "Single search",
                        loadonce : "true"
                    });
                    grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:false});
                    $("#searchText").on('keypress',function(){
                       var text = $("#searchText").val();
                        var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
                        $.extend(postdata,{filters:'',searchField: 'name', searchOper: 'bw', searchString: text});
                        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: text.length>0, postData: postdata });
                        grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);

                });
```

Comment: If you use Guriddo jqGrid there is a build-in search method for this purpose called **filterInput** [Demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/searching/search_all/index.html)

Comment: thanks Tony !  I'll try Guriddo grid  . It is looking nice solution however I need to use it in salesforce  .

Comment: this is the working solution for above question . i have used example from other answers .